# How to convert ObjectResult to JsonResult?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    var result = db.GetMenuMaster();
    //Convert result to Json
}
```

We need to convert the result set that we got from the database to json, only then it can be used in javascript and Angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
  DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
  var result = db.GetMenuMaster();
  return new JsonResult() { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can try this as well:-

```
  return Json(new { result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimized:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
        var result = db.GetMenuMaster();

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = result,
            ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            ContentType = "application/json",
            MaxJsonLength  = int.MaxValue,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```